# ModelState is marked invalid for an empty non-required field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

A bit of a mystery. I have a viewmodel with a Year property:

```
public class TradeSpendingSalesViewModel
{       
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AllowTypeSelect { get; set; }
    public string AllowType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YearsSelect { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
```

If I post an empty viewmodel to my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TradeSpendingSalesViewModel vm)
{
    var allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    foreach (var e in allErrors)
    {
        Response.Write(e.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

Then I get a single error with a message of: "The Year field is required."

Since I haven't annotated the viewmodel Year field with the `Required` attribute, I'm unclear why this error is being generated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My first guess would be that it is throwing an exception that you're not setting year and it's null? if you made year a Nullable<int> does it not throw the required message?

I still wouldn't expect it to be required, it's a shot in the dark

Answer (score 18):

ValueTypes by default are implicitly marked as `Required` in mvc. This was done for purpose, actually, because they by definition are non-nullable.

I would suggest you to set `Year` as `int?`, otherwise, if it's not correct in your case, you may change to false

`DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes`

in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: you verified my thoughts from my answer above... +1 for you :)

Comment: Non-Nullable Values are REQUIRED always. If you want to have a non-required Integer value you have to set it as nullable.

Answer (score 0):

It's still can be an issue in .NET Core projects. I found a solution here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-required-attribute

.NET will mark your parameter as invalid if it's not a nullable type as required. You can set the `SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes` property to true in your `MvcOptions`. Example in `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers(option =>
{
    option.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;
});
```

When you set this up. It will only check only the required attribute. Or you can use the "?" mark to make your properties nullable, and that'll work too.